# Optimised EmEditor Macro to transpose and transform tab delimited data

Tags: performance, emeditor

I currently have a large tab delimited data set that looks like this (n is simply a number, there are more than 4 Headers), an initial Headers column that repeats, followed by at most, 2 columns of data (sometimes only one):

Input file:

Hdr1 A1 B1
Hdr2 A2 B2
Hdr3 A3 B3
Hdrn An Bn
Hdr1 C1
Hdr2 C2
Hdr3 C3
Hdrn Cn
Hdr1 D1 E1
Hdr2 D2 E2
Hdr2 D3 E3
Hdrn Dn En

I need to transpose and transform the data so output looks similar to this (so the repeating headers are removed and the data remains):

Hdr1    Hdr2    Hdr3    Hdrn
A1  A2  A3  An
B1  B2  B3  Bn
C1  C2  C3  Cn
D1  D2  D3  Dn
E1  E2  E3  En

Any ideas for how to do this with an Optimised EmEditor javascript Macro would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there only two groups (upper half and lower half, divided by the center line) in the Input file? If so, we can simplify the task.

Comment: The first column (header column) repeats thousands of times in the source, as there are thousands of records. There are at most 2 columns of data in the source file (after the Header column), but there are also instances where there is only potentially only 1 column of data, like this. I've edited the original example to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript macro for you:

```
sSeparator = "Hdr1";
sDelimiter = "\t";
sNL = "\r\n";
Redraw = false;
document.CellMode = true;   // Must be cell selection mode
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4323);  // Clear All Bookmarks in This Document
document.Filter("^" + sSeparator,0,eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0,0,0);
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(3927);  // Bookmark All
document.Filter("",0,0,0,0,0);    // Reset Filter
if( document.BookmarkCount == 0 ) {
    alert( "Cannot find any lines that begin with \"" + sSeparator + "\"" );
    Quit();
}

document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
x1 = 1;
y1 = 1;
nLines = 0;
nMaxCol = document.GetColumns();
str = "";

for( ;; ) {
    bStop = false;
    if( document.selection.NextBookmark() ) {  // if next bookmark found
        y2 = document.selection.GetActivePointY(eePosCellLogical);
    }
    else {
        y2 = document.GetLines();    // if bookmark does NOT exist at end of document
        bStop = true;
    }
    if( nLines == 0 ) {
        nLines = y2 - y1;
    }
    else {
        if( nLines != y2 - y1 ) {
            alert( "Number of lines between " + sSeparator + " is not same. Check the format of the input file." );
            Quit();
        }
    }

    for( iCol = x1; iCol <= nMaxCol; ++iCol ) {
        s = document.GetCell( y1, iCol, eeCellIncludeQuotes );
        if( s.length == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
        str += s;
        str += sDelimiter;
        str += document.GetColumn( iCol, sDelimiter, eeCellIncludeQuotes, y1 + 1, y2 - y1 - 1 );
        str += sNL;
    }
    
    y1 = y2;
    
    if( bStop ) {
        break;
    }
    x1 = 2;  // don't need the first column except the first time
}

editor.NewFile();
document.selection.Text = str;  // insert copied text
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22529);  // set TSV mode
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `Transpose.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, select **Run Transpose.jsee** in the **Macros** menu.

Comment: Excellent - thank you Yutaka, works as expected.